# Comparing two rows from two different tables for updated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one history and one actual

HistoryTable

```
ActualCalcID DSID        FormatID    RollupId    BD                                       BID         DFID        FMID        Year        Name                                     TID         SID         TyId
------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
18           40          3           1           Test Edit VB                             2           1           1           2016        CCG Contribution Margin (000s) - Test    4           101         3
18           40          3           1           Test Edit VB1                            2           1           1           2016        CCG Contribution Margin (000s) - Test1   4           101         3
```

ActualTable

```
ActualCalcID DSID        FormatID    RollupId    BD                                       BID         DFID        FMID        Year        Name                                     TID         SID         TyId
------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
18           40          4           2           Test Edit VB2                            2           1           2           2016        CCG Contribution Margin (000s) - Test2   5           101         5
```

When user clicks on a button in UI, the row from ActualTable is moved to HistoryTable with the help of an trigger (basically Archiving).

I need which columns have changed when the trigger run completed, in below format

```
Changed Field | Changed Field Content

FormatId | 3

Rollup Id | 2

BD | Test Edit VB1

FMID | 2

Name | CCG Contribution Margin (000s) - Test1

TID | 5

TypeId | 5
```

I think I did not ask my question properly. I want to compare the latest row from history table and the row from actual tables to check which columns have changed. It might be different at different times, some times there will be 4 column changed, sometimes 5, sometimes 1. the output table needs to be logged with only entry for changed column.

Comment: Either use a union with hardcoded columnames or query the metadata to do it dynamically (so it will still work when you add or drop columns). The latter is a little bit complicated, because you also need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: I want to compare the latest row from history table and the row from actual tables to check which columns have changed. It might be different at different times, some times there will be 4 column changed, sometimes 5, sometimes 1. the output table needs to be logged with only entry for changed column. Can this be done dynamically? Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Ok, fine. Suppose you get that information. Just exactly what do you plan to do with it? If, as you seem to infer, only the changed columns are written to the history table, that means the second row of your example history table would be (null, null, null, null, Test Edit VB1). If that is indeed the case, it's going to be mighty difficult to find the last unchanged value of every field.

Comment: I exactly need that.the fields from UI are mapped to the DB..Let's say there are 5 fields in UI..take the first five columns from Actual table...the current values in db for those fields are 18,40,4,2,Test Edit VB2...Now I go to UI..change first and third field from 18,4 to 19,5. the current row in the Actual table will be inserted in history table using trigger and new row will be inserted in Actuals with value 19,40,5,2,Test Edit VB2. Now i want to create a report which will show that these two values have changed from last update

Comment: .Similarly, in next edit I update Test Edit VB2 to Test Edit VB3. The current row in Actuals is moved to History and Actuals will have 19,40,5,2,Test Edit VB3.. the report will show that one field is changed from last update that is column BD..the output table will have two columns Changed field and content and the inserted records in that table will be the actual columns changed and its value may be old or new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'FormatId' AS [Changed Field], CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), FormatId) AS [Changed Field Content] FROM Actual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rollup Id', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), RollupId) FROM Actual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BD', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), BD) FROM Actual UNION ALL
SELECT 'FMID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), FMID) FROM Actual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Name) FROM Actual UNION ALL
SELECT 'TID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), TID) FROM Actual UNION ALL
SELECT 'TypeId', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), TID) FROM Actual
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Table valued constructor` with `cross apply` to unpivot the data

```
select [Changed Field] , [Changed Field Content]
from yourtable
cross apply
(
values ('FormatId',CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), FormatId)),
(Rollup Id', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), RollupId)),
('BD', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), BD)),
('FMID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), FMID)),
('Name', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Name)),
('TID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), TID)),
('TypeId', CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), TID))
) 
cs ([Changed Field] , [Changed Field Content])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTPUT` after your `INSERT` to get the inserted row. You need to apply this in your trigger.

```
DECLARE @TableVar TABLE(
    ChangedField VARCHAR(50)                       
    ,FormatId INT
    ,RollupId INT
    ,BD VARCHAR(50)
    ,FMID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(250)
    ,TID INT
    ,TypeId INT
)

INSERT HistoryTable
    OUTPUT 'Changed Field Content'
            ,inserted.FormatId
            ,inserted.RollupId
            ,inserted.BD
            ,inserted.FMID
            ,inserted.Name
            ,inserted.TID
            ,inserted.TypeId
        INTO @TableVar
VALUES ('', '', ...)

SELECT * FROM @TableVar
```